# Connecting UIButton within custom UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, swift, uibutton

I have a UITableView containing a custom UITableViewCell, each cell contains a button that when pressed should take the user to a new page that corresponds with the cell that the button belongs to. I currently have the UIButton connected to my UITableViewCell class and in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method I have added:

```
let aSelector : Selector = "largeMap"
cell.MapImageButton.addTarget(self, action: aSelector, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

My largeMap method looks like this:

```
func largeMap(sender: UIButton!) {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("largeMapView", sender: self)
    println(sender.tag.description)
    largeMapView.image = UIImage(data: manager.contentsAtPath(documentsPath+"/Flight"+(sender.tag.description)+"/Map.png")!)!
}
```

Since this didn't work I tried having my method as just:

```
func largeMap(sender: UIButton!) {
}
```

I am still getting the following error when I run the app on my device and select one of the buttons:

```
2015-01-09 09:23:46.457 FlightTracker[872:167441] -[FlightTracker.FlightsViewController largeMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14553d7b0
2015-01-09 09:23:46.462 FlightTracker[872:167441] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FlightTracker.FlightsViewController largeMap]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14553d7b0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185f5659c 0x1966ac0e4 0x185f5d664 0x185f5a418 0x185e5eb6c 0x18a73cd34 0x18a725e48 0x18a73c6d0 0x18a73c35c 0x18a7358b0 0x18a708fa8 0x18a9a7f58 0x18a707510 0x185f0e9ec 0x185f0dc90 0x185f0bd40 0x185e390a4 0x18efdb5a4 0x18a76e3c0 0x1000cd76c 0x1000cd7ac 0x196d1aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What is wrong with my selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to add your Button as Sender to your function, you need to add a ":" at the end of your function name:

Like:

```
let aSelector : Selector = "largeMap:"
```

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks for brining that to my attention :)